# what did "the diplomatic origins" do?

Tags: phrase-meaning

the diplomatic origins of the Great War and its aftermath Versailles, which **carried away four empires and an entire generation of young men**; the personal summitry behind the night Stalin and Churchill divided Europe, which foreshadowed the coming of the Cold War; the asymmetrical diplomacy behind the making of ANZUS – or the Australian–New Zealand–United States Security Treaty, which has endured for over fifty years; and, finally, the diplomacy of the global economic system, comprising, inter alia, the activities of transnational corporations and intergovernmental organizations, as well as the diplomacy of civil society organizations, which opened up new
pathways for the conduct of diplomacy while facilitating the involvement of new participants.

carry out means:[this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carry%20away) and meaning of words are clear, but what is themeaning of phrase? what did "the diplomatic origins" do?

Comment: does the sentence start with "the diplomatic origins" or is there something else before?

Comment: @acekidpro - Welcome to ELL :-). To understand better the policy on answers across SE sites I recommend the [help] pages, especially [this one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I've belatedly come across this question, and have to comment on OP's accuracy. As described by https://academic.oup.com/book/34861/chapter-abstract/298269760 (reached via minimal Googling) it relates to a book titled "Diplomatic origins of the Great War and Versailles", and the abstract continues with "...looks at the diplomatic origins of the Great War and its aftermath Versailles," etc. So, as a question of English comprehension, it should be parsed as "This book looks at the diplomatic origins of the Great War and its aftermath Versailles," and so on, which is somewhat less opaque.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have found the wrong meaning of "carry away". Here it means "got rid of", not "aroused". (Actually, I do not think "carry away" in the active is ever used for "arouse", only in the passive "He got carried away").

Secondly, you are misparsing. It was the war which carried away four empires and generation of young men, not the diplomatic origins.

Comment: is "wich" releated to " Great War and its aftermath Versailles " ?
does it mean that "great war and versailles" first deleted four empires & second create an "very new" young diplomats?

Comment: "Which" does refer to " the Great War and its aftermath Versailles", but the association is loose. It was clearly the Great Way, not Versailles, that carried away a generation of young men. Arguably both events were involved in carrying away four empires. The relation of the "diplomtic origins" to the end of the passage is not quite clear because you have quoted it out of context (and possibly omitted some text before); but yes, the passage is listing a number of diplomatic activities over the twentieth century, of which the "diplomatic origins of the Great War" were one.

Comment: do you mean that:   (1)great war --> (2)abolished all generation of young diplomats. and
 then: (1) + (2) -->contributed to abolishing 4 empires.

Comment: No, The "generation of young men" has nothing whatever to do with diplomats: it is the generation of European men of all walks of life who were largely wiped out. Dismantling four empires was another consequence of the Great War. The text is reminding the reader of the devastating effects of the war and its aftermath, not saying that these effects were of any special significance for the future of diplomacy.

Comment: could you say this simply? I am elementary English translator.  " The "generation of young men" has nothing whatever to do with diplomats: it is the generation of European men of all walks of life who were largely wiped out. Dismantling four empires was another consequence of the Great War. "

Comment: It means so many soldiers of similar age  were killed in the war that a generation was nearly wiped out.